# How to show and hide divs when selecting radio buttons in form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have form structure like this:

```html
<div id="q1">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ano1" id="f4"> Yes <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ne1" id="q2"> No
</div>
<div id="q2" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="tmo"> T-mobile <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="o2"> O2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="vodafone"> Vodafone <br>
</div>
<div id="f4" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif1"> Tarif 1 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif2"> Tarif 2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif3"> Tarif 3 <br> Question? <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="roaming"> Roaming <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="pay"> Payments <br>
</div>
```

Idea is that after selecting radio button with ID "f4" a div "f4" will show up and so on.

And in div "q2" I need the same, after selecting radio buttons I need other div to show up.

Is it also possible to show 2 or more divs by selecting one radio button? If so, how?

Comment: You are reusing IDs--they must be unique in the document.

Comment: First you need to know that the id must be unique, you can use custom attribute data-target for example

Comment: ok so lets say the divs would be name_div or something ok?

Comment: You have repeated `ID` attributes. An `ID` attribute must be unique on a page. You should either use the value of the checkbox or a data attribute to target the relevent `div`. Look in to the `on('change')` function and `toggle()`, or `hide()`/`show()` functions in jQuery. Have a go and post the code you have tried if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to get what you want, and use custom attribute to define the targeted div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-target]').click(function() {
    $('.none').hide();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
      $(target).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q1">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ano1" data-target="#f4,#f5"> Yes <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ne1" data-target="q2"> No
</div>
<div id="q2" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="tmo"> T-mobile <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="o2"> O2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="vodafone"> Vodafone <br>
</div>
<div id="f4" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif1"> Tarif 1 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif2"> Tarif 2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif3"> Tarif 3 <br> Question? <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="roaming"> Roaming <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="pay"> Payments <br>
</div>

<div id="f5" class="none">
  Question? <br>
Seconde div
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know what I am doing wrong but nothing happens when I select radio button..

Comment: @TomášVítů did you try the snippet in my answer or in your own code?

Comment: the code in the snippet works but when I copy it to my html it does not..

Comment: @TomášVítů you should add jquery library, and you should copy the html code because i changed it, i added custom attribute `data-target=""`, have another look

Comment: @TomášVítů inspect console, and see if it throws an error

Comment: it gave me an error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined so I changed the order of my scripts so the library is the first one, no error now but it still does nothing..

Comment: now it works! great thanks.. but I have another issue, is it possbile to use data-target to show 2 divs?

Comment: @TomášVítů yes you can by using css selector inside data-target .. i edited my answer so it fits with your request ... take a look and if the answer helped then please accept answer :)

Comment: thanks!!! one more thing.. I need that the div in which I select an option to stay visible if you know what I mean.. When I select an option, the div appears instead of that div I selected an option from

Comment: @TomášVítů i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: the divs appear instead of each other for example there are 2 radio buttons in div1 and after selection, this div disappears and div2 appears instead and I want div1 to stay after I select radio button..

Answer (score 0):

Change id attribute to `data-id` and add change event on radios like,

```js
$('[data-id]').on('change',function(){
  $('.none').hide();
  $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).show();
});
```

```css
.none{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q1">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ano1" data-id="f4"> Yes <br>
  <input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ne1" data-id="q2"> No
</div>
<div id="q2" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="tmo"> T-mobile <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="o2"> O2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="vodafone"> Vodafone <br>
</div>
<div id="f4" class="none">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif1"> Tarif 1 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif2"> Tarif 2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif3"> Tarif 3 <br> Question? <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="roaming"> Roaming <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="pay"> Payments <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what should be displayed when. But below an example how it can be achieved using CSS. I had to remove `id=q1`

```css
.f4,
.q2 {
  display: none;
}

#f4:checked~.f4 {
  display: block;
}

#q2:checked~.q2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Question? <br>
<input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ano1" id="f4"> Yes <br>
<input type="radio" name="novecislo" value="Ne1" id="q2" checked> No

<div class="q2">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="tmo"> T-mobile <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="o2"> O2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="operator" value="vodafone"> Vodafone <br>
</div>
<div class="f4">
  Question? <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif1"> Tarif 1 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif2"> Tarif 2 <br>
  <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif3"> Tarif 3 <br> Question? <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="roaming"> Roaming <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="pay"> Payments <br>
</div>
```